# Converting Cocoa objects in PyObjC return value to Python objects?

Tags: python, cocoa, wifi, pyobjc, corewlan

I'm experimenting with retrieving network scan results from CoreWLAN in Python using PyObjC, with code that looks like:

```
from CoreWLAN import *
client = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient()
en0 = client.interface()
scan, _ = en0.scanForNetworksWithSSID_error_(None, None)
```

This returns an `NSSet` of `CWNetwork` objects into `scan`. I can convert the NSSet into a Python `set` easily enough, but is there a similarly straightforward way to convert the CWNetwork instances into Python `dict` or `NamedTuple` structures?

I only care about data members of the CWNetwork objects, and do not need to be able to pass messages to them again.

*Note:* the code above depends on an API introduced in OS X 10.10, and will not run on earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: CWNetwork objects contain CWChannel objects that I'd like to convert too. I know how to convert them manually but was curious if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: You'll have to convert them manually.